# What is wrong with my native query in jpa?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I'm sending a very simple query to the database, but I'm getting an error. It feels like I'm missing something very simple. I guess it wouldn't allow me to create it because the word order is a keyword on the h2 db, so I put it in quotation marks within the table annotation.

```java
   @Query(value = "select * from `ORDER` o where o.basket_id= :basketId ", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<Order> getOrderByBasketId(Long basketId);
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "`ORDER`")
public class Order extends BaseExtendedModel{
            private BigDecimal price;
            @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
            private OrderStatus orderStatus;
            @OneToOne
            private Customer customer;
            @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
            private Basket basket;
            @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "order")
            private OrderAddress orderAddress;
}
```

```json
{
    "errorMessage": "could not prepare statement; SQL [select * from `ORDER` o where o.basket_id= ? ]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement"
}
```

Comment: Try adding name of the database before you call ORDER , so something like "select * from `dbname.ORDER`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is easier to identidy when you have a look at the logs. You'll see an entry like this:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ORDER" not found; SQL statement:

So let's see what SQL statements are executed. So we add the following to `application.properties`

> spring.jpa.show-sql=true

Assuming you let spring boot create your tables, you will see the following:

> Hibernate: drop table if exists "order" CASCADE
> Hibernate: create table "order" ...

And when we hit the repository method we see

> select * from `ORDER` o where o.name= ?  [42102-200]

So why did it create the table in lowercase, even though we specified `` @Table(name = "`ORDER`") ``?

The default for `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy` is `org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy`, which

- replaces dots with underscores
- changes CamelCase to snake_case
- lower-cases table names.

But we want it to take the names we use in `@Table`. That works when setting the property to `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`.

Yor native query will need the matching casing though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use index parameters

```
@Query(value = "select * from `ORDER` o where o.basket_id= ?1", nativeQuery = true)
Optional<Order> getOrderByBasketId(Long basketId);
```

or named parameters

```
@Query(value = "select * from `ORDER` o where o.basket_id= :basketId", nativeQuery = true)
Optional<Order> getOrderByBasketId(@Param("basketId") Long basketId);
```

Comment: thx for answer but now i am getting this error  ( Table "ORDER" not found; SQL statement:
select * from `order` o where o.customer_id= ? )   I have a table named order.

Comment: Then your application is likely not connected to the database you think it is.

Comment: No, I can get other entities from db. Only the order object has such a problem. The db connection is successful.